# Grails 4 fresh plugin fails to resolve gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, grails, grails-4

Sample project here: https://github.com/Trebla7th/grails4-plugin-test

Looking into upgrading some applications and plugins to grails 4.  Starting with a fresh project just to get the feel for it, using an "out of the box" grails plugin fails to compile.

```
grailsVersion=4.0.1
gorm.version=7.0.2.RELEASE
```

gradle 5.1.1

Attempting to compile gives

```
Error |
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'. Type 'gradle dependencies' for more information
```

Running 'gradle dependencies --stacktrace' gives the following

```
Configuring signAndPublish task for project :
Applying dependency management to configuration 'assets' in project 'grails4-plugin-test'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'gspCompile' in project 'grails4-plugin-test'
Applying dependency management to configuration 'developmentOnly' in project 'grails4-plugin-test'
Resolving global dependency management for project 'grails4-plugin-test'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'grails4-plugin-test'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each([Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'grails4-plugin-test'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
...snip...
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
...snip... 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each([Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)[Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.grails.gradle.plugin.core.GrailsGradlePlugin.buildClasspath(GrailsGradlePlugin.groovy:608)
```

This project was created using "create-plugin" and then unchanged other than some proxy configuration to get the dependencies to download.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem.  Since you can recreate it in a fresh project, would you do that and share the project on GitHub or some other channel and link to it from here?

Comment: Added link to github project in problem description, though I'm not optimistic since this was literally just `grails create-plugin` with no changes...  not sure why you'd have a different initial data set

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: UGH, discovered that for some reason my PATH had gradle 4.10.2 on it and that was interfering...  removing that fixed the dependence resolution...  confused-user error.

Comment: That makes sense.  Glad you sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

Had a conflicting gradle version on my PATH, removing that allowed the gradle dependencies to resolve...  hopefully nobody else hits this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue when I created a grails 4.0.0 plugin. The `build.gradle` file has a dependency to `org.grails:grails-plugin-testing` which need to be removed in order to get gradle to build the app successfully. There's an github issue here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11293.

Solution:

`//    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"`